# How to test a half wave bridge with a multimeter

Tags: diodes, multimeter, bridge-rectifier

I found a box of LAS-8500P half wave bridge interface drivers in my attic.  How can I test them with a multimeter to see if they are any good?

Data sheet
https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/531203/Semtech/LAS-8500P/1

Comment: Welcome. A multimeter or DVM can only test for dead shorts in complex IC's. But with a 12 VDC to 24 VDC supply you can do a light-load test. A proper test means an pulse generator to drive it and oscilloscope to see the output pulses.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming used pulls or something like that, if you put your multimeter on diode range and test the outputs and inputs relative to ground and you see diode junctions there, it's "probably" good.

If they are brand new, they're probably good, period.

A more thorough test, even a simple functional test, is going to require building up a circuit similar to those in the datasheet and making measurements.